# Formatting Get-ACL output

Tags: powershell, format, acl, export-to-csv

I am trying to use the `Get-ACL` function to scan subfolders in a directory.  I'm modifying a working script I found here that converts the output to a `.csv` file.  It would be great if I could get the output so that each row contains ***all*** the `IdentityReference` values for each folder. However my best attempts result with this error:

> Method invocation failed because [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.

Here is the code:

```
$OutFile = "C:\Admin\Permissions.csv"
$Header = "FolderPath,IdentityReference,AccessControlType,IsInherited,InheritanceFlags,PropagationFlags"
Del $OutFile
Add-Content -Value $Header -Path $OutFile 

$RootPath = "I:\Users\ES"

$Folders = GCI $RootPath\* | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}

foreach ($Folder in $Folders){
    $ACLs = get-acl $Folder.fullname | ForEach-Object { $_.Access  }
    Foreach ($ACL in $ACLs){
        $OutIR = $ACL.IdentityReference
        $OutIR +=  ","
    }
    $OutInfo = $Folder.Fullname + "," + $OutIR + "," + $ACL.AccessControlType + "," + $ACL.IsInherited + "," + $ACL.InheritanceFlags + "," + $ACL.PropagationFlags
    Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $OutFile
}
```

I tried to use the variable `$OutIR` to catch all the `IdentityReferences` and then add `$OutIR` to the results at the end. Each folder would be listed and on the same row, all the `IdentityReference` would be displayed.

---

UPDATED> Thanks a lot for all of the help so far!  Both codes work (awesome!), but I would really like to tweak the output. BTW, this my first time asking for help here, its awesome to have real scripters actually looking at this!

I'm using Powershell 4.0 on a Windows 2012 R2 machine.

An example of the output I'm getting is:

```
"I:\Users\ES\aalvarez","NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM","Allow","False","ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit","None"
"I:\Users\ES\aalvarez","BUILTIN\Administrators","Allow","False","ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit","None"
"I:\Users\ES\aalvarez","XXX\aralvare","Allow","False","ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit","None"
```

The output I'd like to have is:

```
"I:\Users\ES\aalvarez","NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM","BUILTIN\Administrators","XXX\aralvare","Allow","False","ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit","None"
```

The idea is that I can put my 1000+ users in a spreadsheet and quickly compare their folder ACLs.  Thanks again!

Comment: Try to convert all your output variables into strings, i.e. `$Folder.Fullname.ToString()`

Comment: What version of Powershell are you using?

Comment: Can you provide an example of exactly what you want the output to look like?

Comment: I included my Powershell version and an example of the desired output - Thanks!

Comment: Type, inheritance and flags may differ across ACEs of the same ACL.

Answer (score 1):

You don't get the result you're expecting, because you're using the loop variable of your inner loop *outside* of that loop.

Change this:

```
foreach ($Folder in $Folders){
  $ACLs = get-acl $Folder.fullname | ForEach-Object { $_.Access  }
  Foreach ($ACL in $ACLs){
    $OutIR = $ACL.IdentityReference
    $OutIR +=  ","
  }
  $OutInfo = $Folder.Fullname + "," + $OutIR + "," + $ACL.AccessControlType +
             "," + $ACL.IsInherited + "," + $ACL.InheritanceFlags +
             "," + $ACL.PropagationFlags
  Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $OutFile
}
```

into this:

```
$Folders | % {
  $fpath = $_.FullName
  Get-Acl $fpath | select -Expand Access | % {
    $fpath + "," + $_.IdentityReference + "," + $_.AccessControlType + "," +
      $_.IsInherited + "," + $_.InheritanceFlags + "," + $_.PropagationFlags
  }
} | Add-Content -Path $OutFile
```

Since you want to create comma-separated output, you could entirely avoid manual string concatenation by using the `ConvertTo-Csv` cmdlet and a calculated property for the folder name:

```
$Folders | % {
  $fpath = $_.FullName
  Get-Acl $fpath | select -Expand Access |
    select @{n='FolderName';e={$fpath}}, IdentityReference, AccessControlType,
      IsInherited, InheritanceFlags, PropagationFlags
} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | select -Skip 1 | Add-Content -Path $OutFile
```

If you don't mind the header line you could also directly export the data to a CSV:

```
$Folders | % {
  ...
} | Export-Csv $OutFile -NoType
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw mjolinor already comment and he probably has something better because he's awesome, but here's what I would go for if it were me. I like having an object to work with when all is said and done in case I want to query it later I've got it to fall back on. Then we can export it to a CSV instead of building one the hard way like you were doing.

- Create an empty array.
- Get your ACLs, and loop through them kind of like you are now.
- Create a PSCustomObject for each ACL with the properties that you want in your output file.
- Add that object to the array you made before.
- When all is done export-csv the array to a file.

Here's the code that will do that:

```
$OutFile = "C:\Admin\Permissions.csv"
$ACLList =@()
Del $OutFile
$RootPath = "I:\Users\ES"

$Folders = GCI $RootPath\* | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}

foreach ($Folder in $Folders){
    $ACLs = get-acl $Folder.fullname | ForEach-Object { $_.Access  }
    Foreach ($ACL in $ACLs){
    $OutInfo = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
      FolderPath = $Folder.Fullname
      IdentityReference = $ACL.IdentityReference.ToString()
      AccessControlType = $ACL.AccessControlType.ToString()
      IsInherited = $ACL.IsInherited
      InheritanceFlags = $ACL.InheritanceFlags
      PropagationFlags = $ACL.PropagationFlags}
    $ACLList+=$OutInfo
    }
}
$ACLList|select FolderPath,IdentityReference,AccessControlType,IsInherited,InheritanceFlags,PropagationFlags|export-csv C:\temp\Permissions.csv -NoTypeInformation
```